# How to change default language in React-TinyMCE?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I just installed and configured react-tinymce in my React JS Application. Everything work fine !

But, the user interface is in English, and my client would like to have it in French. So, I followed the advice on tinymce documentation, but I have this error message that appears in my text editor: "Failed to load plugin url: https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/langs/fr_FR.js" in a red block, and the interface is still in English.

This is my code for this element:

```
     <Editor
           apiKey='XXX'
           initialValue="<p>Contenu de l'information</p>"
           cloudChannel='Default'
           init={{
             plugins: 'link image code table imagetools media ',
             toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code | table | image',
             language: 'fr_FR',
             images_upload_url: true,
           }}

        onEditorChange={this.handleEditorChange}
    />
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

you must download lang in  this [link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/) and copy file in side your app

```
// Import TinyMCE
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';

// Any plugins you want to use has to be imported
import 'tinymce/plugins/paste';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';
import './langs/fa_IR.js';

import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css';
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css';
import 'tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css';
import 'tinymce/themes/silver';


// Initialize the app
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  language:'fa_IR',
  plugins: ['paste', 'link']
});
```

Comment: i donwload langs/fa_IR.js

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the language pack you wish to use from [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/language-packages/).
2. Unpack the language file into your public/langs folder.
3. set this setting:

```
tinymce.init({
    language: "fa_IR",
    language_url: "/langs/fa_IR.js",
    directionality :"rtl",      
});
```

Comment: Why is this answer not marked as the solution? It's simple and perfect. Tks @Moh3eN

Answer (score 0):

CDN seems to be down for tinymce. So as a workaround you could do following steps:-

1) Download language pack from [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/language-packages/)

2) Store language.js onto some folder say inside tinymcd/language

3) Use language_url parameter to point to the location you stored js file - absolute url

```
tinymce.init({
  language_url : 'http://example.com/tinymcd/language/fr_FR.js'  // site absolute URL
});
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE Cloud platform does not currently host the language files so you need to download the language file(s) you need and host them locally on your server and then reference them using the `language_url` configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  in  initConfig.js  file;

import zh_Cn from './langs/zh_CN.js';

export const initConfig = {

    language: 'zh_CN',
    language_url: zh_Cn,

......

}
```

```
// in Editor.js file

<Editor

        id="Editor1" 
        init={initConfig}   
        disabled={false}
        onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}

// other props
        
/>
```